# Ubuntu (17.04) desktop is not turning on after an unexpected shutdown

Tags: backup, shutdown, 17.04

My computer stopped working due to a power outage while my computer was on, after the power came back I could no longer use my computer, it would turn on but would not let me use the desktop. I would want to know at least how I could backup my home folder.

When I boot up I see this screen:

[image: Screenshot]

After I select the first option Ubuntu I see this screen with error messages:

[image: Image link with console error messages]

It would be very helpful If you could show me how I could backup my home folder.

Comment: are you able to boot from a bootable USB drive?

Comment: Please edit your question to include answers to the following questions.  1) Did you run the file system check as noted in the second image?  2) What file system is on your root partition (if you didn't explicitly change it, it's likely ext4)?  3) Is your home directory on a separate partition from your root directory?

Comment: Yes, I am able to boot from a USB drive

Comment: @b_laoshi I don't know how to rin the file system. I did not change any root partitions. My home is in the same partition as the root directory